# How to align different elements inside a Button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I am trying to build the following component,

[image]

Following is my code,

```kotlin
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_check_circle) , contentDescription = "")
    Text(text = "John Doe", textAlign = TextAlign.Start)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward), contentDescription = "",
        alignment = Alignment.TopEnd)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Spacer`:

1. `Modifier.width(10.dp)` will give you static size.
2. `Modifier.weight(1f))` will fill all available space.

```
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_undo) , contentDescription = "")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
    Text(text = "John Doe")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_redo), contentDescription = "")
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the components inside your button compose function with a `Row` and set the `horizontalArrangement` to `Arrangement.SpaceBetween`. See the modified version of your code snippet below.

```
       Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_subject_24),
            contentDescription = "", alignment = Alignment.CenterStart)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Text(text = "John Doe", textAlign = TextAlign.Start, modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterVertically))
    }
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_subject_24),
        contentDescription = "")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made an alternative that closely matches your layout using `ConstraintLayout`.

Put in your `build.gradle` file (module scope inside) inside `dependencies`:

```
// To use constraint layout in compose
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02"
```

**NOTE:** I'm using icons provided by android studio itself, remember to use yours if they are custom icons. To do this just change the `id` parameter of `painterResource` referring to the appropriate drawables.

In your compose function that displays the button, use the following code:

```kotlin
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = Color(0xFF847EBA),
        contentColor = Color.White
    ),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 4.dp),
    onClick = {}
) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        val (startIcon, text, endIcon) = createRefs()
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(startIcon) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
            },
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_check_circle_outline),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
                start.linkTo(startIcon.end, margin = 8.dp)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
            },
            text = "John Doe"
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(endIcon) {
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            },
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_navigate_next),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

**Visual effect:**

[image: personalized button using constraint layout to align children]

Comment: Hi @Pierre Vieira, I think they should have exposed the modifier of RowScope which the Button component uses internally and it would have solved the problem without adding any further composables.

One more thing, the Icon library it states in the documentation that it is a heavy library and only use if you are using a lot of icons from it

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `Button` is a `RowScope`.
Just apply the `weight` modifier to the `Text` composable:

```
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Image()
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
    Text(text = "John Doe",modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Image()
}
```

[image]